# SQL: Order by asc/desc not working properly on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table in Sql Server 2014 called T_Hours with columns such as:

```
Day       Open            Close           Modified_Date
Mon       17:00:00        20:00:00        12/05/2015
Mon       09:00:00        11:00:00        12/05/2015
Tues      17:00:00        20:00:00        10/27/2015
Tues      09:00:00        11:00:00        10/26/2015
Wed       17:00:00        20:00:00        10/22/2015
Wed       09:00:00        11:00:00        10/20/2015
```

I am trying to order by `Modified_Date desc` and `Day, Open, Close asc` so that the table appears like:

```
Day       Open            Close           Modified_Date
Mon       09:00:00        20:00:00        12/05/2015
Mon       17:00:00        11:00:00        12/05/2015
Tues      09:00:00        20:00:00        10/27/2015
Tues      17:00:00        11:00:00        10/26/2015
Wed       09:00:00        20:00:00        10/22/2015
Wed       17:00:00        11:00:00        10/20/2015
```

I already tried

```
order by `Modified_Date desc, Open asc, Close asc, Day asc`
```

but this only sorts the `Modified_Date` and not the other columns the way I want it to. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What are the datatypes for these columns (is modified_date a datetime thus time is being sorted as well?)  Seems to me it's working.  First the engine sorts by `modified_date`... then by `OPEN asc`.  `Close asc` is pointless here as `Modified_Date` and `open` generate unique sort sequence.  If you had another record on 12/5/2015 for Open at 09:00 and a close of 17:00 it would be BEFORE your current record...

Comment: You are thinking in reference to columns and not rows.  The ORDER By clause orders rows, based on data in the columns.  It's not going to rearrange the data in the row.  What you are wanting to do is impossible unless you break the row apart and put it back together again which makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @xQbert modified_date is a datetime, as well as open/time

Comment: Well you're not (neither are we) seeing the time portion of modified_date  so if time is in the data, that may be all it can sort by.  if time is irrelevant then you may need to cast modified_Date as a date only field so the other sorting is valid.  But as the data presently shows, it's sorting exactly like you asked it to: 1st by modified Date desc 2nd by Open Date ASC, third by close date then by day It's just that modified_Date and Open are specific enough that no other criteria matters.  Why don't you think it's not working?  What isn't in the order it should be and why?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Hello (couldn't resist!),

It seems as if you have all of the elements in your order by clause contained in single quotes - did you try to remove the single quotes around it? Additionally, open, close, and day are reserved words in SQL - you should wrap those in square brackets.
You currently have: `order by 'Modified_Date desc, Open asc, Close asc, Day asc'`
Try to switch it to: You currently have: `order by Modified_Date desc, [Open] asc, [Close] asc, [Day] asc`

Good Luck!